# Backspace not doing the expected on mobile

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

```
        function createAdditionalDiv() {
            let innerBox = document.createElement('div')
            innerBox.contentEditable = "true"
            innerBox.id = totalBoxes++;
            innerBox.className = "mainBox"
            let mainBox = document.getElementById('mainContainer')
            innerBox.addEventListener('keyup', checkTrigger)
            mainBox.appendChild(innerBox);
            $(".mainBox").on("keydown", function (event) {
                if (event.key === 'Backspace' || event.key === 'Delete') {
                    let deletionMarker = document.createElement('span');
                    deletionMarker.hidden = true
                    deletionMarker.id = "deletionMarker"
                    putDataToCarentPos(deletionMarker.outerHTML.toString(), false);
                    let previousTag = document.querySelector('#deletionMarker').previousSibling
                    while (!previousTag.textContent) {
                        previousTag = previousTag.previousSibling
                    }
                    if (previousTag.tagName === "SPAN") {
                        if (previousTag.className === "toDelete") {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            document.getElementById('deletionMarker').remove();
                            document.querySelector('.toDelete').remove()
                        }
                        else {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            document.getElementById('deletionMarker').remove();
                            previousTag.className = 'toDelete';
                            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById('deletionMarker').remove();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Hey, guys so I have this function as a part of my code which is not working on my mobile from a deployed app. Its hosted here. https://ideaflow-project-qsii.vercel.app/ . So this is a notekeeping type of application where typing "<>" allows you to autocomplete from other divs. The key functionality of backspace doesnt work ,i.e. on adding a selection from a dropdown and pressing back  it selects the div on backspace and deletes it entirely on a second backspace. seems to be working in emulators and web app, but from a mobile app it just replicates the span after pressing back and adds instead of deleting chars.May I know what part of this function I need to alter to get it working.

Basically double backspace to delete feature seems to be getting messed up on mobiles but works with emulators and web apps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem you are experiencing is quite complex and may require further analysis. However, here's a revised version of your code with comments to clarify how it works. I've also made a few potential adjustments that might help solve the problem, although I can't guarantee that this will completely resolve the issue

```
function createAdditionalDiv() {
    let innerBox = document.createElement('div');
    innerBox.contentEditable = "true";
    innerBox.id = `box_${totalBoxes++}`; // Using backticks to create a unique identifier
    innerBox.className = "mainBox";

    let mainBox = document.getElementById('mainContainer');
    innerBox.addEventListener('input', checkTrigger); // Using 'input' event instead of 'keyup'

    mainBox.appendChild(innerBox);

    // Using 'input' event instead of 'keydown' with jQuery
    $(".mainBox").on("input", function (event) {
        if (event.inputType === 'deleteContentBackward') {
            let deletionMarker = document.createElement('span');
            deletionMarker.hidden = true;
            deletionMarker.id = "deletionMarker";

            putDataToCarentPos(deletionMarker.outerHTML.toString(), false);

            let previousTag = document.querySelector('#deletionMarker').previousSibling;

            while (previousTag && !previousTag.textContent) {
                previousTag = previousTag.previousSibling;
            }

            if (previousTag && previousTag.tagName === "SPAN") {
                if (previousTag.className === "toDelete") {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    document.getElementById('deletionMarker').remove();
                    previousTag.remove(); // Remove the previous element
                } else {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    document.getElementById('deletionMarker').remove();
                    previousTag.className = 'toDelete';
                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                }
            } else {
                document.getElementById('deletionMarker').remove();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Also, you should do these things :

- Check Keyboard Event Handling: Ensure the "keydown" event works correctly on mobile devices by adding debug console logs or alerts to verify if the checkTrigger function is triggered when pressing "Backspace"
- Try Different Events: Experiment with alternative events like "keyup" or "input" to detect text deletion if "Backspace" handling behaves unexpectedly on mobile devices
- Use jQuery Event Handling: Prevent conflicts between native JavaScript (addEventListener) and jQuery ($(".mainBox").on(...)) event handling. Confirm that "Backspace" events are correctly managed with jQuery on mobile devices
- Test Across Different Mobile Browsers: to determine if the issue is browser-specific or maybe even try it on different device to check if the issue can be device-specific
- Utilize Mobile Debugging Tools : such as Chrome DevTools for Android to inspect events and DOM elements, to provide insights into the behavior when "Backspace" is pressed on a mobile device

I tried my best to answer but it might not help you at all